# JS "межпроцесное" взаимодействие

Tags: javascript, node.js

1. Есть таймер, например, на 1 секунду. Он выполняет какое-то действие и если оно длится дольше 1 секунды начинаются глюки ибо следующий проход таймера запускает опять это действие. Как сделать чтобы эти таймеры не мешали друг другу? Что-то вроде volatile?
2. Примерно та же ситуация, но скрипт запущен в кластере например на pm2. Два экземпляра скрита мешают друг другу при работе например с той же БД. Использование в качестве флага о блокировки другим процессом поля в БД не помогает, потому что нет гарантии что они одновременно не попытаются его записать в одинаковое значение. Пока использую костыль с lock файлом, но должно же быть более правильно решение?

Answer (score 1):

1. Например:

   - ставить «лок» в какую-нибудь глобальную переменную;
   - запускать не `setInterval`,  а `setTimeout` в конце выполнения функции.
2. В (нормальных) БД можно просто лочить таблицу (запись/всю базу).